# SyntaxError : Invalid syntax jedi

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

There is a problem showing in my vs-code editor **`SyntaxError: Invalid syntax jedi`** I don't know why this problem showing it's bothering me so much and there are some weird symbols on my editor `←[0m` `←[m` you can see this image can anyone tell how to remove both of this from vs-code editor these will be really helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out I don't know somehow my vs-code packages are disabled all I do just enabled them and the problem was gone.

Comment: I encountered same issue, and used same way to solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem by using your solution, just disable the package and enable again and the error message was gone.

Answer (score -1):

VSCode shows `invalid syntax jedi` even when you miss `()` for parameters on your defined function.

Answer (score -1):

I had a simple code that contains an if condition and it was getting to me `Syntax Error: invalid syntax` and the I got the parentheses exist there was wrong and the error happened just for the `()` in my if condition. :)